# Create dataframe row with positive numbers and other with negative

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe called **Utilidad**

```
    Argentina Bolivia   Chile   España  Uruguay
2004       3     6       1        3       2
2005       5     1       4        1       5
```

And I calculate the difference between 2004 and 2005 using

```
     Utilidad.ix['resta']=Utilidad.ix[2005]-Utilidad.ix[2004]
```

Now I'm trying to create two additional rows, one with the result of the difference when is positive and the other one with the negatives, something like this

```
    Argentina Bolivia   Chile   España  Uruguay
2004       3     6       1        3       2
2005       5     1       4        1       5
resta      2    -5       3       -2       3
positive   2     0       3        0       3
negative   0    -5       0       -2       0
```

The only I have managed to do is to have an additional column which tells me wheter "resta" is positive or not, using

```
Utilidad.ix['boleano'][Utilidad.ix['resta']>0]
```

Can someone help me to create this two additional rows?

Thanks

Comment: Aside: recommended practice is now to prefer `.loc` and `.iloc` to the somewhat unpredictable magic of `.ix`.

Comment: good to know that, I'm just starting with pandas, i will read the doc about .loc and .iloc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`numpy.clip` will be handy here, or just calculate it .

```
In [35]:

Utilidad.ix['positive']=np.clip(Utilidad.ix['resta'], 0, np.inf)
Utilidad.ix['negative']=np.clip(Utilidad.ix['resta'], -np.inf, 0)
#or
Utilidad.ix['positive']=(Utilidad.ix['resta']+Utilidad.ix['resta'].abs())/2
Utilidad.ix['negative']=(Utilidad.ix['resta']-Utilidad.ix['resta'].abs())/2
print Utilidad
          Argentina  Bolivia  Chile  España  Uruguay
id                                                  
2004              3        6      1       3        2
2005              5        1      4       1        5
resta             2       -5      3      -2        3
positive          2        0      3       0        3
negative          0       -5      0      -2        0

[5 rows x 5 columns]
```

Some speed comparisons:

```
%timeit (Utilidad.ix['resta']-Utilidad.ix['resta'].abs())/2
1000 loops, best of 3: 627 µs per loop
In [36]:

%timeit Utilidad.ix['positive'] = np.where(Utilidad.ix['resta'] > 0, Utilidad.ix['resta'], 0)
1000 loops, best of 3: 647 µs per loop
In [38]:

%timeit Utilidad.ix['positive']=np.clip(Utilidad.ix['resta'], 0, 100)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.6 ms per loop
In [45]:

%timeit Utilidad.ix['resta'].clip_upper(0)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.32 ms per loop
```

Comment: There's also `.clip_upper` and `.clip_lower` on `Series` themselves.

Comment: @DSM, `clip`, or `.clip_xxx` methods are actually slow in this case, only direct calculation is able to be slightly faster than the boolean indexing version.

Comment: @DSM np.minimum / maximum seem to be __significantly__ faster here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `numpy.where`

```
df.ix['positive'] = np.where(df.ix['resta'] > 0, df.ix['resta'], 0)
df.ix['negative'] = np.where(df.ix['resta'] < 0, df.ix['resta'], 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

The observation to make here is that negative is the minimum of 0 and the row:

```
In [11]: np.minimum(df.loc['resta'], 0)  # negative
Out[11]:
Argentina    0
Bolivia     -5
Chile        0
España      -2
Uruguay      0
Name: resta, dtype: int64

In [12]: np.maximum(df.loc['resta'], 0)  # positive
Out[12]:
Argentina    2
Bolivia      0
Chile        3
España       0
Uruguay      3
Name: resta, dtype: int64
```

*Note: If you are concerned about speed then it would make sense to transpose the DataFrame, since appending columns is much cheaper than appending rows.*

You can append a row using loc:

```
df.loc['negative'] = np.minimum(df.loc['resta'], 0)
```